# custom authorize attribute or policy based authorization handler

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I should check the custom header is present eg:["apikey"] and then check in the database thatgiven key is present. if not present return unauthorized. should i use authorization attribute or policy based authorization handler?

Comment: If you can use a policy, it is encouraged to use a policy. Writing custom Authorizationattributes should be a last resort.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. In order to help you, we have to fully understand your question. Please be specific and don't skip on the details. Please read ["How to ask a good queatios"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I agree with @Marco, using Policy based authorization will make your code more reusable and cleaner.

Comment: As it is simple one to validate, i was confused which one is better to go.  Even I find it policy based auth handler is a better approach and can add more req handlers in the future.

Comment: I dont agree.  Using policies is contrived and "stiff" you end up hardcoding these policies anyways.  I have found that for simple validations is better to use an attribute and for other things like Permissions Based(not roled based) security is better to use an attribute and make it database driven,

Comment: This whole "policy is king" doctrine has been preached by microsoft in the same way microsoft has been preaching "Entity Framework is king" for years. In my opinion neither assumption is true.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than authorization handler, I find custom authentication handler is a better approach for this scenario and implemented the same.